# how to make build success even the Test Case got failed?

Tags: java, api, rest, maven, serenity-bdd

I am running a suite of APIs test cases which is build on maven Project. There are some failure in Test cases due to this my entire build is getting failed. how to make build success even the Test Case got failed. Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test

Maven build failure solution

Comment: Sorry to say that but that does not make sense. If tests are failed your build is not Ok... that's the intention of tests... What you can make while changing the behaviour is to define a build as unstable in case of failed unit tests?

Comment: intension is - to run test cases in spinnaker pipeline, after running all test case the build should be success and it should generate the container  image for further deployment as part of CI-CD

Answer (score 1):

Adding `-DskipTests` to your maven build command will build without running the tests.

E.g: `mvn clean install -DskipTests`

Answer (score 0):

Pls try
mvn clean verify serenity:aggregate -Dtags=smokesuite Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true

Ref: baeldung.com/maven-ignore-test-results